# Wrong date format C#, Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to get my date in the correct format(dd/mm/yyyy). At the moment its in this format: MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS When I change it to dd/mm/yyyy, it works in the database(Oracle). As soon as I run it in my app I get exception: IndexOutOfRange at :

```
this.InfoList9.Add(dr["start_rcv_datetime"].ToString());
```

Please see my code below.

```
public List<String> InfoList = new List<String>();

private void populatelblDate()
{
    conn.Open();
    string query;
    query = "select to_char(dg.start_rcv_datetime,'dd/mm/yyyy') from dc_pallet dp, dc_pallet_stock dps , dc_grv dg , sku s ,prod_size ps,colour c ,purch_order_carton_sku pocs , dc_crane_instruc dci where dps.pallet_id_no = '" + palletId.ToString() + "' and dp.pallet_id_no = dps.pallet_id_no and dg.dc_grv_id_no = dps.dc_grv_id_no and dg.order_no = dps.order_no and dg.company_id_no = dps.company_id_no and s.company_id_no = dps.company_id_no and s.company_id_no = dg.company_id_no and dps.company_id_no = c.company_id_no and dps.company_id_no = ps.company_id_no and s.prod_size_id_no = ps.prod_size_id_no and s.colour_id_no = c.colour_id_no and dps.company_id_no = ps.company_id_no and pocs.order_no = dps.order_no and pocs.carton_code = dps.carton_code and pocs.company_id_no = dps.company_id_no and pocs.sku_id_no = s.sku_id_no and dci.pallet_id_no(+) = dp.pallet_id_no";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        this.InfoList.Add(dr["start_rcv_datetime"].ToString());
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}

private void frmInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    populatelblDate();
    lbl1.Text = this.InfoList[0];
}
```

Then I have a prev and next button as well...

Comment: Off-topic: Are you sure that you need all these joins in your SQL query?

Comment: :) That's not the whole query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `IndexOutOfRange` exception suggests that the *immediate* problem is that the result set doesn't contain a column of `start_rcv_datetime` - presumably because of the `to_char` conversion.

Don't deal with *strings* at the database side at all. Fetch the value as a `DateTime`, and then format it at the *client* in whatever you want to.

Use `dr.GetDateTime` to fetch the value, having removed the `to_char` part from your query:

```
query = "select dg.start_rcv_datetime from ...";

using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn))
{
    using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        int dateColumn = dr.GetOrdinal("start_rcv_datetime");
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            DateTime date = dr.GetDateTime(0);
            // Or whatever - consider cultural implications
            string text = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            InfoList.Add(text);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note the `using` statements - you should always make sure you clean up your database-related resources.)

Comment: Just to add my case when transferring data from Oracle table to Ms Sql. In source table (Oracle) there is a field of DATE type. During transfer I used ExecuteReader and value of this field is written as string to destination table (Ms Sql). However, since year in question was 2032, later down the pipeline it was translated as 1932. Hence, for such cases it is mandatory to use this approach (get field type and, if date, format accordingly).

Comment: @Vladimir.RL: A better solution would be to avoid the "field written as string to destination table" part. If you don't have any formatting and parsing, it's hard for that sort of thing to happen...

Answer (score 0):

Your first column doesn't have a name andso you cannot retrieve it with `"start_rcv_datetime"`

The immediate solution would be to change the sql to read

```
query = "select to_char(dg.start_rcv_datetime,'dd/mm/yyyy') as start_rcv_datetime from dc_pallet dp, dc_pallet_stock dps , dc_grv dg , sku s ,prod_size ps,colour c ,purch_order_carton_sku pocs , dc_crane_instruc dci where dps.pallet_id_no = '" + palletId.ToString() + "' and dp.pallet_id_no = dps.pallet_id_no and dg.dc_grv_id_no = dps.dc_grv_id_no and dg.order_no = dps.order_no and dg.company_id_no = dps.company_id_no and s.company_id_no = dps.company_id_no and s.company_id_no = dg.company_id_no and dps.company_id_no = c.company_id_no and dps.company_id_no = ps.company_id_no and s.prod_size_id_no = ps.prod_size_id_no and s.colour_id_no = c.colour_id_no and dps.company_id_no = ps.company_id_no and pocs.order_no = dps.order_no and pocs.carton_code = dps.carton_code and pocs.company_id_no = dps.company_id_no and pocs.sku_id_no = s.sku_id_no and dci.pallet_id_no(+) = dp.pallet_id_no";
```

However you could simply return the date as a datetime from the database and then use string.Format on the result

eg.

```
this.InfoList.Add(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dr["start_rcv_datetime"]));
```